# uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library

Tags: android, cordova

I recently upgraded cordova-android to version 12, my app no longer builds and I get the following error

uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library

I understand that I need to raise my min version to 21 or higher, which I have done in my config.xml file:-

```
<platform name="android">
...
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="24" />
...
</platform>
```

I've removed and added the platform numerous times and I still get a failed build with the error above. Everything I google ends with the same answer (change the android-minSdkVersion version in the config.xml file).

I'm pulling my hair out as I'm sure it's something obvious I'm  missing, thanks for any help, and if you require more information (plugins used etc then let me know).

Full error:

```
> Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
C:\www\cordova\app\platforms\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0] C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\8fa35d5508191c4f9f8ca09de1273d1b\transformed\jetified-core-splashscreen-1.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 19
        Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 19,
                or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
                or use tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.core.splashscreen" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

See https://developer.android.com/r/studio-ui/build/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0] C:\Users\user\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\8fa35d5508191c4f9f8ca09de1273d1b\transformed\jetified-core-splashscreen-1.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 19
        Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 19,
                or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
                or use tools:overrideLibrary="androidx.core.splashscreen" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have likely set the min sdk version in the gradle build config. See https://developer.android.com/build/gradle-tips#combine-multiple-product-flavors which shows using `minSdkVersion` in a gradle file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've used agent ransack to search the whole directory for the string minSdkVersion and I can't see any file that sets that to 19 other than build files inside the platform folder that are generated when "cordova build android" is executed. I tried editing these files and running the build command again but they are reset to 19.

Comment: @pjknight then you might somehow have another library that uses minSdkVersion. hard to say since I don't know anything about cordova. But if you're certain that you're not setting the min sdk to 19 in your own code, look to your frameworks and dependencies. Perhaps try taking out your dependencies one at a time until things start working, and then look more deeply from there.

Comment: I've just created a new project with cordova which isn't using any plugins and I'm getting the same error.

Comment: @pjknight if you have a basically empty project that can't build, that would imply that cordova-android itself is somehow broken. I can't help you here, sorry. Again, I don't know anything about it.